# How to pull data from Quandl faster

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

I am using the following approach to populate a column in my dataframe with prices from Quandl:
import pandas as pd

```
dict1 = [
        {'Date': '2016-11-27','Ticker': 'AAPL'},
        {'Date': '2016-11-28','Ticker': 'MSFT'},
]
data= pd.DataFrame(dict1)
data['Date']      = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data['close-0'] = data.apply(lookup_close, axis='columns', args=('Ticker','Date',))
```

where lookup_close is defined as:

```
def lookup_close(row, tickerColumn, dateColumn):
    try:
        ticker=row['Ticker'][:-3] 
        start_date=row[dateColumn] 
        end_date=row[dateColumn]   
        price = quandl.get('WIKI/'+ticker, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)['Adj. Close'].values[0]
        return price
    except: 
        return np.nan
```

This approach works but is painfully slow for large dataframes than the one in my example above. Could anyone suggest a way of how to make this faster?

Comment: for your data frame `ticker=row['Ticker'][:-3]` will return a string excluding the last three chars , if `AAPL` is in the `row['Ticker']` ,the `row['Ticker'][:-3]` will be `A`. If there is leading and tripling whitespace use `strip()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take note `WIKI` seems to deprecated in Quandl. [Here](https://www.quandl.com/databases/WIKIP/documentation)  it says

```
Note: As of April 11, 2018 this data feed is no longer actively supported by the Quandl community. We will continue to host this data feed on Quandl, but we do not recommend using it for investment or analysis.
```

That being said, assuming you can migrate aways from `WIKI` dataset, I find it is much faster to have a local dump of the Quandl dataset, and do a dataframe lookup from local file instead. Unfortunately, for `WIKI` it seems like the `latest_full_data` is no longer available.

Once you have a local .csv for the tickers that you are interested at, you can load it in dataframe and use pandas `merge`, `merge_asof`, or `join` to do lookup.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I was not aware. That sounds like a much faster alternative, I will reach out to them and see if that is possible.

Comment: @Tartaglia: I personally use `EOD` dataset from QuoteMedia. But it is not free. The advantage is that they have an API to do local dump quite efficiently. The local dump is one gigantic `.csv` which you can chop off to per-ticker .csv if you so need

Comment: That is a nice alternative, thank you for pointing that  out. I might look it into that if I cannot find a free alternative...